# Is it possible to have a Riak instance created in-process for testing purposes?

Tags: python, jenkins, riak

Similarly to https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis, when I can patch `Redis` class and have Redis as a service available in-process, can I do the same with Riak? The goal is a CI build and testing. Apart from installing a Riak cluster targeting build/test purposes, I haven't found an acceptable solution.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer specifically for Python? Also do you realize that a mock class is not like having the service running on process but just a piece of code simulating replies ? If yes then a mock class shouldn't be hard to write especially from the PBP definitikn

Comment: @dams is right. If you need a fully-functional Riak though, probably the simplest option would be to install Riak on a virtual machine, configure it to run as a single node, and then package the VM as an image. You could then spawn a VM + run a simple script or a configuration management tool (Chef, Puppet, etc.) to have Riak up and running.

Comment: Also, riak in a docker image can be used.

Comment: As Riak has two types of API (HTTP and Protocol Buffer), it is important to indicate which type of API you mean.